# Looking Forward for someone to doing something

Tags: grammar

I was wondering about "looking forward to" usage but adding in another subject. Is the following correct:

I am looking forward for Peter to go (/going/be going) on holidays?

I understand the basic usage (I am looking forward to going on holidays), but what about squeezing in another subject?

Comment: By "squeezing in another subject", do you mean just adding more information?

Comment: It's always "looking forward _to_" whether the anticipated event involves you or someone else.

Comment: @CWill No. See my answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

In fact, the object, not the subject is what we are dealing with here:

"[I] am [looking forward (to)] [going on holidays]."

subject ---------- verb ---------- object

"[I] am [looking forward (to)] [(someone) going on holidays]"

In the first case, *my* is implied in place of (someone) and in the OP's example, *Peter* takes the place. Neither is the subject here. The object phrase is "(someone) going on holidays", or whatever.

Comment: Thanks, so just to be clear, is the following the correct usage: I am looking forward to Peter going on holidays?

Comment: Yes, that is what both @Kris and I said.

Comment: “Peter” is the difference between the two sentences.   The relationship between “Peter” and “going” looks, superficially, like a subject-verb relationship.   But you say we are not dealing with a subject.   Would you care to explain the relationship between “Peter” and “going”? … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott I think the answer has all it needs to have.